# SQLite primary key does not work

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, primary-key, auto-increment

I have problem with primary key. I'm using  `Xamarin.Forms` `PCL` project with `SQLite-net` (1.4.118.0) NuGet library.
I forgot to add property with attributes `PrimaryKey`, `AutoIncrement` at the beginning.
Later i added primary key but it does not work (Id column has only "0" values). 
It only works if i create new class with new name and `PrimaryKey`, `AutoIncrement` attributes.
How to recreate my table in `Sqlite` from the scratch with original class name?
Where is table metadata stored in `Sqlite`, how i can clean it?

```
public class ApproachViewModelNew 
    {       
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }       
        public string ApproachName { get; set; }
    public string ApproachDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the structure of our tables, we gotta handle these changes by "Migration" process. Otherwise we gotta delete our database and create it again. You can delete app's DB by deleting App's cache in device settings